# Верно ли стоят запятые у Пушкина

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, деепричастный-оборот, деепричастия, обстоятельство

> Из мертвой главы гробовая змия 
>   Шипя() между тем выползала;

Почему на месте скобок не стоит запятая? Согласно справочнику Лопатина, даже если деепричастие имеет значение образа действия, но отделено от глагола другими членами предложения, то запятая ставится.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Попробуйте переделать текст в прозаический:

*Гробовая змия, **шипя**, между тем выползала из мертвой главы.*

*Между тем из мертвой главы, **шипя**, выползала гробовая змея.*

Как мы видим, **глагольность в деепричастии присутствует**, в стихах же используется обычная **инверсия**, к тому же вообще **характерная для того времени.**

2) **А теперь о справочнике Лопатина.** Лично я обращаюсь к нему во вторую очередь, так как информация в нем упрощена и сокращена, а правила Розенталя остаются действующими.

У Розенталя сказано вот что (п.6): "Указывая на образ действия, одиночное деепричастие обычно **приближается по значению к наречию** или к сочетанию существительного с предлогом, употребленному в обстоятельственном значении, и **не обособляется".**

При этом приведено достаточное количество примеров, где необособленное деепричастие не примыкает к глаголу, например: *Аксинья вошла в зал **не постучавшись** (Ш.); Девочка вбежала в комнату рыдая; Иной простак **не шутя** так подумает.*

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=113#pp113

Вот пример из современной литературы; Говорила она **не умолкая**, и все на какие-то вселенские темы [Дина Рубина. Белая голубка Кордовы (2008-2009)]

Таким образом, **излишняя регламентация** (расположение деепричастия рядом с глаголом) препятствует корректному пониманию правила. Это всего лишь **один из признаков** для отсутствия обособления.

Answer (score 4):

Да, действительно, есть такое правило у Лопатина:

> § 71. Деепричастия и деепричастные обороты не обособляются:
>
> 1) если деепричастие непосредственно примыкает к глаголу и имеет
>   значение образа действия: Не спеша бегут лошади среди зеленых
>   холмистых полей (Бун.) — бегут как?; Сергей долго лежал не шевелясь
>   (Вороб.) — лежал как? Такие деепричастия по функции сближаются с
>   наречием: Это упражнение делают сидя на стуле; Он читал лежа; Рассудок
>   мой изнемогает, и молча гибнуть я должна (П.). **Ср., однако, при
>   изменении порядка слов и в результате — подчеркнутом усилении
>   глагольности (обозначении действия): Инженер, лежа, читал свое горное
>   искусство (Фад.); или когда между деепричастием и глаголом находятся
>   другие члены предложения**: Подрагивая, Трофим схватил винтовку,
>   выстрелил... (Шол.). Ср.: По дорожке сада он шел не оглядываясь. — Не
>   оглядываясь, он шел по дорожке сада;

https://orfhographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=121#pp121

Однако обратим внимание, что "между тем" появилось в результате изменения порядка слов - но **не для усиления глагольности**, а для сохранения ритма в поэтическом тексте. У Пушкина, видимо, не было цели усилить глагольность, поэтому он и не выделил деепричастие, для него это наречие:

Из мертвой главы гробовая змия

Шипя между тем выползала;

Выползала ( как?) шипя = с шипением. Важно не действие шипение, а то, что она уже выползает и сейчас исполнит роковое предсказание. Здесь явно **деепричастие непосредственно примыкает к глаголу и имеет  значение образа действия.**

Answer (score 0):

А почему ни у кого нет желания наехать на А. С. за "зм***и***ю?)) Кому-то действительно кажется, что грамматические правила всегда были такие, как сейчас?

Comment: Задайте, пожалуйста, такой вопрос, и вам непременно ответят.  Или "может быть, ответят".

Comment: Sharon, и в каком месте смеяться?

Comment: Да в любом. Так вы сюда пришли посмеяться или будете на вопросы отвечать? Лучше второе, а  то юмористов здесь хватает, а отвечающих мало.  Текучесть кадров, и все такое. Не задерживаются почему-то люди, вот и вы куда-то пропали

Comment: Одно другому («посмеяться» и «отвечать») не мешает, но если здесь всё ещё в порядке вещей глупенькие подколки, то мне и снова пропасть недолго))

Comment: Не волнуйтесь, с моей стороны "глупенькие подколки" вам не грозят, если уж вы так.  А за "общий порядок вещей" я не отвечаю.